# Can DBUtils overcome SQLServer: "The statement must be executed before any results can be obtained."

Tags: sql-server, apache-commons-dbutils

I am trying to insert data into a SqlServer table that has a generated key.  I don't care about the new keys created, but the error I get back seems to suggest I must:

```
java.sql.SQLException: The statement must be executed before any results can be obtained.
```

DBUtils has a (thankfully) simple interface but doesn't seem to be able to overcome this.

Anyone have any ideas?

```
conn = this.dcf.getSqlServerDataSource(database).getConnection();
        conn.setAutoCommit(false);

        qRunner.insertBatch(conn, sql, new ArrayHandler(), parms);
```

Answer (score 0):

There is another method in DBUtils:

```
qRunner.batch(conn, sql, parms);
```

This does not require a ResultSetHandler and does not seem to care about the created keys.